# How can I implement this in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have been trying to implement this for an assignment, and since I am a beginner, I am having issues.
[This is what I have to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRT0u.png)

This is my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- BottomAppBar with BottomNavigationView -->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="#157177"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:fabCradleMargin="0dp"
        >

        <!-- BottomNavigationView -->
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#157177"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_bar"

            />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <!-- Floating Action button -->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tint="#157177"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[This is how it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yVLu.png)

The Bottom navigation is not fully overlapping the BottomAppBar and also the icons show faded unless clicked. I did try to search, but most code online gives errors or is too complex for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom view for this because in bottom navigation view one cannot set custom space ratio. So i suggest to create custom view using either LinearLayout Or ConstrainLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving the **elevation** as **`0dp`**? It might help you to achieve the uniform look without shadow behind the FAB button.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:elevation="0dp"/>
```